# Submenu item isn't clickable

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I want a dynamically submenu. Now I tried this way:

```
@interface AppController()
@property(strong) Accounts * accView;
@property (weak) IBOutlet NSMenuItem *serverMenu;
@end

@implementation AppController

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    _accView = [[Accounts alloc] initWithNibName:@"Accounts" bundle:nil];
    [self.viewk addSubview:[_accView view]];
    [[_accView view] setFrame:self.viewk.bounds];

    NSMenuItem * testItem = [[NSMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Test" action:@selector(test:) keyEquivalent:@""];

    [[_serverMenu submenu] addItem:testItem];

}

- (void)test:(id)test {

}
```

Then it get's added but I can't click on it. It's like this:

[image]

How can enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to assign a target to your NSMenuItem, like

```
[testItem setTarget:self];
```

Comment: Thanks you SOOO much. I saw in the docs something like this validateMenuItem: Do I need to implement this?

Comment: `-validateMenuItem:` is optional, you only need it if your menu item needs to be enabled/disabled dynamically based on some condition.